# What is wrong with this date?

Tags: datetime

Can anyone explain what is so erroneous about this date?

```
Class.SMSCallbackController.doGet: line 42, column 1
14:55:07.039 (39781770)|FATAL_ERROR|System.TypeException: Invalid date/time: 2014-06-16T15:55:00Z
```

It's in EXACTLY the same format as the one on the documentation.

If it helps, the date is received like this: "2014-06-16T15:55:00.000", but I take the first 19 characters out using .substring() and append a 'Z' to the end before doing Datetime.valueOf(date_as_string).

Comment: What documentation are you referring to? The example given in the [DateTime.valueOf documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_valueOf) is `2008-10-5 12:20:20`.

Comment: Hmm, I just noticed that. I was going by this: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm and the 'Examples' at the top.

Comment: It looks like that link is for OfficeToolkit

Comment: Hmm, it just came up when I searched for date formats in salesforce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Documentation says that the format of the string passed to Datetime.valueOf should be 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'. So maybe that's why it gave you an error.

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_valueOf

I have also used the JSON deserlialize to get the date time, as shown below. You could use that as well.

```
System.debug((datetime)json.deserialize('"2014-06-16T15:55:00.000Z"', datetime.class));
```